# how to fix dialog error with recycleview?

Tags: android, dialog, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I am setting dialog in recycle adaptor but it give error.

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application.

I search alot but all answer says change context to getActivity but in recycle adaptor I have no choice like that.

I search a lot in google and stack overflow  but found no solution

```java
@NonNull
@Override
public StopRecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view=LayoutInflater.from(context1).inflate(R.layout.bus_recycle_lyout,viewGroup,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final StopRecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    item1=item.get(i);
    viewHolder.stop.setText(item1.getStop());
    viewHolder.stop_serial.setText(item1.getStopTitle());
    mdialog=new Dialog(context1);
    mdialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_stop_dialog);
    mdialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    viewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                EditText update_stop=mdialog.findViewById(R.id.update_stop);
                update_stop.setText("hlw");
                mdialog.show();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(context1,"error  "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return item.size();
}
```

I expect the dialog opens when user click on recycle view.

Comment: Please format code properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check like this where you are getting exception

```
if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isVisible()) {
}
```

or

```
if(!context.isFinishing()){

  builder.show();
}
```